# R data.table to calculate new columns from existing columns bases in certain conditions

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say I have the following data table:

```
dta <- data.table(
  criteria = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B'),
  phase = list('block3', c('block1', 'block2'), 'block2', 'block2', 'block3', 'block1'),
  start_val = c(12.0, 1.0, 7.0, 7.0, 12.0, 1.0),
  end_val = c(15.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 15.0, 6.0),
  max_val = c(13.0, 8.0, 9.5, 11.0, 15.0, 6.0)
)
```

from which I need the resulting table with two additional column's, `cor_start` and `cor_end`

```
dtb <- data.table(
  criteria = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B'),
  phase = list('block3', c('block1', 'block2'), 'block2', 'block2', 'block3', 'block1'),
  start_val = c(12.0, 1.0, 7.0, 7.0, 12.0, 1.0),
  end_val = c(15.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 15.0, 6.0),
  max_val = c(13.0, 8.0, 9.5, 11.0, 15.0, 6.0),
  cor_start = c(12.0, 1.0, 8.0, 9.5, 13.0, 6.0),
  cor_end = c(13.0, 8.0, 9.5, 11.0, 15.0, 6.0)
)
```

the new columns need to be calculated with reference to `phases` column by checking if there is any previous row with the current matching phase value.

For better understanding, in this example:

- row 3 has a matching phase of block2 in row 2
- row 4 has a matching phase of block2 in row 3
- row 5 has a matching phase of block3 in row 1
- row 6 has a matching phase of block1 in row 2

however row 1 and row 2 have no previous matching phase rows. Note that the `phase` is of type list.

So, when there is a previous matching row, below are the conditions:

```
if (max_val in previous matching row is < end_val in current row)
  cor_start = previous matching row max_val
  cor_end = current row end_val

if (max_val in previous matching row is > end_val in current row)
  cor_start = current row end_val
  cor_end = current row end_val
```

and when there is no previous matching row, below are the conditions:

```
  cor_start = current row start_val
  cor_end = current row max_val
```

I looked into shift(), but could not figure out on how to set the above conditions ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
dta_transformed <- dta[,.(rn = .I, phase = unlist(phase)), by = setdiff(names(dta), 'phase')][
  , shifted_max := shift(max_val), by = phase][
    shifted_max < end_val, `:=` (cor_start = shifted_max, cor_end = end_val), by = phase][
      shifted_max > end_val, `:=` (cor_start = end_val, cor_end = end_val), by = phase][
        is.na(cor_start), `:=` (cor_start = start_val, cor_end = max_val), by = phase][
          , phase := paste(phase, collapse = ","), by = rn][!duplicated(rn),][
            , c("rn", "shifted_max") := NULL]
```

However, the output I get is:

```
   criteria         phase start_val end_val max_val cor_start cor_end
1:        A        block3        12      15    13.0      12.0      13
2:        A block1,block2         1      11     8.0       1.0       8
3:        B        block2         7      11     9.5       8.0      11
4:        A        block2         7      11    11.0       9.5      11
5:        A        block3        12      15    15.0      13.0      15
6:        B        block1         1       6     6.0       6.0       6
```

Could it be that in row number 3 the `cor_end` should be 11 in your desired output? As the previous matching row (2) has lower `max_val`, therefore the current `end_val` (11) should be taken?

Also the `tidyverse` approach, slightly more readable:

```
library(tidyverse)

dta %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  unnest(phase) %>%
  group_by(phase) %>%
  mutate(
    cor_start = case_when(
      lag(max_val) < end_val ~ lag(max_val),
      lag(max_val) > end_val ~ end_val,
      TRUE ~ start_val
    ),
    cor_end = if_else(!is.na(lag(max_val)), end_val, max_val)
  ) %>% group_by(rn) %>%
  mutate(
    phase = paste(phase, collapse = ",")
  ) %>% ungroup() %>% select(-rn) %>% distinct()
```

Comment: Great! thank you for your support. In row 3 case 'cor_end' should be the current max_val of 9.5 and not 11 as it is a numeric input which can be dynamically changed by the user upto 11. So, the remaining range from 9.5 to 11 can be used in any further instance of the same phase. Assigning `cor_end = max_val` in `shifted_max < end_val` condition fixed it. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! Consider upvoting or accepting the answer if it's been helpful.

Comment: yes, I have already upvoted but unfortunately it is only recorded for now as I do not have enough points yet. Will be reflected once I earn more.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach which uses `pmin()` instead of `ifelse()` and utilises the `fill` parameter of the `shift()` function. Furthermore, it reduces the number of grouping operations:

```
library(data.table)
dta[, rn := .I]
dta[dta[, .(phase2 = unlist(phase)), by = rn], on = "rn"][
  , `:=`(cor_start = pmin(shift(max_val, fill = start_val[1]), end_val), 
         cor_end = max_val), by = phase2][
    , .SD[1], by = rn][
      , c("rn", "phase2") := NULL][]
```

> ```
>   criteria         phase start_val end_val max_val cor_start cor_end
> 1:        A        block3        12      15    13.0      12.0    13.0
> 2:        A block1,block2         1      11     8.0       1.0     8.0
> 3:        B        block2         7      11     9.5       8.0     9.5
> 4:        A        block2         7      11    11.0       9.5    11.0
> 5:        A        block3        12      15    15.0      13.0    15.0
> 6:        B        block1         1       6     6.0       6.0     6.0
> ```